# Dynamically Populating Image/Excerpt/LInks from Pages in WordPress

Tags: theme-development

I am after some guidance with the following HTML to WordPress conversion.

Based on the linked image (see HTML Divs screen image), which has the following three divs, which will be individual pages within my WordPress site, after conversion, i.e.:

see:> [html Divs](http://i1148.photobucket.com/albums/o565/fatboysammy/html_file.png)

```
1) Solar Pool Heating
2) Domestic Hot Water &
3) Solar Electric
```

Can somebody please let me know how through the use of the WordPress loop and built in functions, I can obtain the image for each div from the main page as well as an excerpt of the page content for each of the divs together with the "Read More" which would then take me to the actual page to read all of the page?

I'm not sure if this is possible but I have always wanted to know how this can be done as this would assist my understanding of this area.

Hopefully someone can assist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can load content from other pages via the [get_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) function:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'include' => array( 5, 6, 7 ) // your page IDs
);
$my_pages = get_pages( $args );

foreach( $my_pages as $page ){
    setup_postdata( $page );
    the_title();
    the_post_thumbnail();
    the_excerpt();
    the_permalink();
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Milo but can I ask you a few queries, how does the_post_thumbnail() function work - does it just grab any image attached to that page id? Also, how does the_excerpt() function work - say I just want to pick up the first 50 chars of the page id, which may consist of two paragraphs in that 50 chars? Does a substr() need to be performed or does the excerpt get placed elsewhere? Thanks.

Comment: @softprinciples see [the_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt), [the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail), and [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) in codex.

Comment: unfortnately I cannot get the get_pages to work for me. Tried the code above and it didn't retrieve back anything? Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: @softprinciples - did you change the page ids to your pages? I'd have to see it in context as it works for me. what do you see when you `print_r($my_pages);` after the get_pages call?